# Expressing the output product using dot

Tags: products, feyncalc, dot

I have an expression of the form `Hbar.H` where `H` and `Hbar` are vectors. How can I get the output so that it has dot in the expression i.e.

```
H = {a,b,c}
J = {d,e,f}
```

mathematica gives for `H.J ---> ad+be+cf`

I want `H.J- ---> a.d+b.e+c.f`

The components have Dirac matrices and I wish to take the trace of the output and hence the trouble.

Comment: `Apply[Dot, #] & /@ (H.J)`

Comment: amazing thanks a lot

Comment: Also `Dot @@@ (H.J)`